# Stuck with this query for MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I am trying to make it show for years in columns and neighborhoods in rows. In the cells I want the total share of trips per neighborhood and per year in percent. I should look like the picture, but the cells need to be i percentage of the total trips. For cell for Downtown and 2015, the percent showing should be 60.67%.

[image]

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Percentage] AS 
    Divide
    (
      [Measures].[Trip Count]
     ,(
        [Measures].[Trip Count]
       ,[start station].[start 
  station]
      )
    ) 
   ,format_string = "percent" 
SELECT 
  [start time].[start time].[YearL].[2014] : [2015] ON COLUMNS
 ,[start station].[start station].[neighborhood] ON ROWS
FROM [Cube];
```

[image]

I want it like the picture above.

Answer (score 0):

Just some smallish tweaks to the script.

The new measure needs to be made aware of the current year and can be used in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Percentage] AS 
    Divide
    (
      ([Measures].[Trip Count],[start time].[start time].CURRENTMEMBER)
     ,(
        [Measures].[Trip Count]
       ,[start station].[start station]
       ,[start time].[start time].CURRENTMEMBER
      )
    ) 
   ,format_string = "percent" 
SELECT 
  [start time].[start time].[YearL].[2014] : [2015] ON COLUMNS
 ,[start station].[start station].[neighborhood] ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE ([Measures].[Percentage]);
```